# How to deploy Angular 9 on heroku?

Tags: angular, heroku, angular9

I am trying to run Angular application on Heroku. I have read many guides, but the solutions do not work in my case.
Application build is successful on Heroku. However, when the application starts, an error occurs.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-heroku",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/angular-heroku'));

app.post('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +  '/dist/angular-heroku/index.html');
});
app.listen(4200);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularHeroku</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
hello
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
world
```

**heroku app logs**
[image: heroku app logs]

I just need code example of how to run the example Angular 9 app (possibly Angular 8) on Heroku. Plz help :(

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is...

1. `git clone https://github.com/xyz/angular.git`
2. `cd angular`
3. `heroku create`
4. `git push heroku master`
5. `heroku ps:scale web=1`
6. `heroku open`

When you push the project using 4th command, all the dependencies are installed automatically. 
Before that, your project should be uploaded to github.

Comment: result: https://secure-sea-59451.herokuapp.com
logs this same like in my post

Comment: you have to generate angular production files using ng build and copy the files from generated dist folder to the public folder in express app (backend).
And follow above steps

Answer (score 0):

Your **package.json** looks like you are using express but it seems like you forgot to add a path to set up your server.

Enter

```
npm install --save express path
```

Then your **package.json** will have express, path inside dependencies.

Inside engines put your node and npm version in **package.json** like

```
"engines": {
  "node": "~8.15.1",
  "npm": "~6.4.1"
}
```

For knowing versions do

```
node -v
npm -v
```

It should work then.

For [Reference](https://codemeals.com/angular-tutorials/deploy-angular-7-app-to-heroku/).

Answer (score 0):

Create server.js file in your project folder:-

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const server = require('http').Server(app);


// Serve only the static files form the angularapp directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/your-application-name'));
 
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/your-application-name/index.html'));
});
 
// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port


server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("App running on port " + port);
})
```

Update the script in package.json file.

```
"start": "node server.js",
"postinstall": "ng build --output-path your-application-name --aot --prod",
```

Make sure dist file is not mention in .gitignore file.

Comment: I think `dist` file should remain in gitignore. Else, we will be commiting the dist files to git.